# Message from the NSAPI plugin: No backend server available for connection: timed out after 10 seconds or idempotent set to OFF

Tags: timeout, weblogic, http-status-code-503

I got the following message from the browser when I ran a long waiting request on my web application:

Message from the NSAPI plugin:

No backend server available for connection: timed out after 10 seconds or idempotent set to OFF.

Also, I got a 503 response code from httpConnection. I assume the server was timeout, but I could not find anything to extend the timeout. The above message was approximately shown after 5 minutes the request was sent. The server is running on WebLogic. Does anyone know where I can change the timeout duration or anyway to work around?

Answer (score 2):

From my experince, most likely it is not related to timeout settings. According to http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/plugins/plugin_params.html, the parameter ConnectTimeoutSecs default value is 10 seconds, which is usually more than enough. The instruction on how to configure the plugin is here http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/plugins/nsapi.html#110496. You did not specify which version of WLS you are using, but the instruction barely changes from version to version.

But before you start to manipulate this parameter, I would suggest, first of all, please make sure your WLS domain is up and running. Secondly, please check your NSAPI plugin to make sure the WLS server DNS name and port you try to connect to are all configured correctly. Third, check with your network admin to make sure there is no firewall between your web server and WLS server. If there is such firewall, make sure the firewall allows your connection traffic between the two.

Comment: I am sorry I did not mean the timeout of the NSAPI plugin, but the time out of the actual server. I think the NSAPI plugin error occurs because the server rejects the connection or something. The connection to the server is initially successful and the process running fine. After 5 minutes, the server somehow timed out or reject the connection, then the NSAPI plug tries to reconnect but unsuccessfully, which will then response back with a 503 error. So I try to find out if there is any server timeout setting to validate my hypothesis.

Answer (score 0):

This usually due to system backup, during which time the web service is unavailable. A retry some time later will be successful. We see this on some federal websites on Sunday afternoons.