# Can not connect to weblogic server (application) via apache proxy module

Tags: java, apache, ssl, proxy, weblogic

I deployed my application to WebLogic Server Version: 10.3.6.0 and enabled the SSl port:7002 on it. i can browse my application locally fine . then want to browse it via apache web server (version 2.2) using the weblogic proxy module. i set all the parameters required in httpd config file. also i create self singed certificate in weblogic and import the certificate to apache (trustCAFile). now when when try to browse via apache server, i get the error:

```
"Failure of server APACHE bridge:
No backend server available for connection: timed out after 10 seconds or 
idempotent set to OFF"
```

---

This part of the log is created in apache server (weblogic module log)

---

```
"Wed Jan 14 19:06:40 2015 <460014212462002> Hdrs to WLS:[Connection]=[Keep-Alive]
Wed Jan 14 19:06:40 2015 <460014212462002> Hdrs to WLS:[WL-Proxy-SSL]=[true]
Wed Jan 14 19:06:40 2015 <460014212462002> Hdrs to WLS:[WL-Proxy-Client-IP]=[192.168.0.25]
Wed Jan 14 19:06:40 2015 <460014212462002> Hdrs to WLS:[Proxy-Client-IP]=[192.168.0.25]
Wed Jan 14 19:06:40 2015 <460014212462002> Hdrs to WLS:[X-Forwarded-For]=[192.168.0.25]
Wed Jan 14 19:06:40 2015 <460014212462002> Hdrs to WLS:[X-WebLogic-KeepAliveSecs]=[30]
Wed Jan 14 19:06:40 2015 <460014212462002> Hdrs to WLS:[X-WebLogic-Force-JVMID]=[unset]
Wed Jan 14 19:06:40 2015 <460014212461931> WARN: GetSessionCallback: No session match found
Wed Jan 14 19:06:40 2015 <460014212462002> INFO: SSL certificate chain validation failed: -6986
Wed Jan 14 19:06:40 2015 <460014212462002>     trusted certs = 1
Wed Jan 14 19:06:40 2015 <460014212462002>      dumping cert chain
Wed Jan 14 19:06:40 2015 <460014212462002>         commonName is www.onlinestuff.af
Wed Jan 14 19:06:40 2015 <460014212461931> WARN: DeleteSessionCallback: No match found!!
Wed Jan 14 19:06:40 2015 <460014212462002> ERROR: SSLWrite failed
Wed Jan 14 19:06:40 2015 <460014212462002> SEND failed (ret=-1) at 805 of file ../nsapi/URL.cpp
Wed Jan 14 19:06:40 2015 <460014212462002> *******Exception type [WRITE_ERROR_TO_SERVER] raised at line 806 of "
```

---

And this is part of the weblogic server log:

---

```
"####<Jan 14, 2015 7:20:36 PM AFT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <aix_machine> <CD> <DynamicJSSEListenThread[DefaultSecure]> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1421247036871> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[DynamicJSSEListenThread[DefaultSecure],9,WebLogicServer]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLENGINE: SSLEngine.setUseClientMode(boolean): value=false.> 
####<Jan 14, 2015 7:20:36 PM AFT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <aix_machine> <CD> <ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'weblogic.socket.Muxer'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1421247036873> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'weblogic.socket.Muxer',5,Thread Group for Queue: 'weblogic.socket.Muxer']]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLENGINE: SSLEngine.unwrap(ByteBuffer,ByteBuffer[]) called: result=Status = OK HandshakeStatus = NEED_TASK
bytesConsumed = 52 bytesProduced = 0.> 
####<Jan 14, 2015 7:20:36 PM AFT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <aix_machine> <CD> <ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'weblogic.socket.Muxer'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1421247036891> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'weblogic.socket.Muxer',5,Thread Group for Queue: 'weblogic.socket.Muxer']]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLENGINE: SSLEngine.wrap(ByteBuffer,ByteBuffer) called: result=Status = OK HandshakeStatus = NEED_UNWRAP
bytesConsumed = 0 bytesProduced = 1264.> 
####<Jan 14, 2015 7:20:36 PM AFT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <aix_machine> <CD> <ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'weblogic.socket.Muxer'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1421247036891> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'weblogic.socket.Muxer',5,Thread Group for Queue: 'weblogic.socket.Muxer']]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLENGINE: SSLEngine.unwrap(ByteBuffer,ByteBuffer[]) called: result=Status = BUFFER_UNDERFLOW HandshakeStatus = NEED_UNWRAP
bytesConsumed = 0 bytesProduced = 0.> "
```

---

Weblogic OS is AIX 7.1 and apache server OS is Windows server 2003 standard

I can attach more details if required

Comment: Does this question about weblogic timeout settings help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15117775/message-from-the-nsapi-plugin-no-backend-server-available-for-connection-timed I edited your question to make it easier to read

Comment: This is about the certification validation chain error i think. because most possibly 10 sec is enough for our environment.